# SQL:check whether a time column is greater than system time

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to know how to check whether a timestamp in a (StartTime Column) is greater than the system time. If greater, it should reset the time stamp into NULL

Is there a way to do that?

Regards.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQLServer? Do you want this as a part of a query or a procedure? You've it all in your tags.

Comment: I am using SQLServer. And I am not sure what is the best option. But it(Query or PRocedure) have to be launched everytime a record is inserted.

Comment: You may want to look into triggers, a BEFORE INSERT trigger...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you could try:

```
UPDATE table SET time = NULL
WHERE time>NOW()
```

If you want it to be auto, try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd BEFORE INSERT ON `table` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    IF NEW.time>NOW() THEN SET NEW.time=NULL; END IF; 
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update table set ts_field = null where ts_field > now()
```

this is for mysql

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @Now datetime = GETDATE()

Update tbl Set
    StartTime=NULL
Where StartTime > @Now
```

Comment: how can I make this execute everytime a record is inserted

Answer (score 1):

```
  create trigger tbl_reset_date
  on tbl
  after insert
  as

  update t
  set time = null
  from tbl t
   join inserted i
     on i.id = t.id
  where i.time > getdate();
```

Comment: Too much Pascal/Delphi (or wherever else you are using `nil`)? :)

Comment: what do you mean by this on i.id = t.id My table name is Product and the column name which has the time is called Ptime. could you edit the code accordingly I am a bit confused. Regards

Comment: Just replace id with whatever the primary key of the table is. Maybe product_id?

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Product_InsteadOfTrigger 
ON Product
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS

  IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 -- limit nested recursion if no work to do
  BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Product
    (
      ProductId,
      PTime 
    )
    SELECT 
      i.ProductId, 
      CASE 
        WHEN i.PTime > GETUTCDATE() 
        THEN NULL 
        ELSE i.PTime 
      END
    FROM 
      inserted i

  END -- if work to do

GO
```